# What is the purpose of static class in C++?

Tags: c++

I recently encountered the definition of static class in C++ while going through the source code of ns2 simulator:

```
static class TCPHeaderClass : public PacketHeaderClass {
public:
        TCPHeaderClass() : PacketHeaderClass("PacketHeader/TCP",
                         sizeof(hdr_tcp)) {
        bind_offset(&hdr_tcp::offset_);
    }
} class_tcphdr;
```

I have never encountered a static class in C++ before. What are the properties and uses of the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is an unusual syntax to declare a static *instance* of `TCPHeaderClass` called `class_tcphdr`, equivalent to

```
class TCPHeaderClass : public PacketHeaderClass {
public:
    TCPHeaderClass() : PacketHeaderClass("PacketHeader/TCP", sizeof(hdr_tcp)) {
        bind_offset(&hdr_tcp::offset_);
    }
};

static TCPHeaderClass class_tcphdr;
```

Comment: I guess it is better to use the singleton pattern so that you know when the class is instantiated.

Answer (score 5):

It is not the class that is static, it is the variable `class_tcphdr`.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
class TCPHeaderClass : public PacketHeaderClass { /* etc. */ };

static TCPHeaderClass class_tcphdr;
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `class tcphdr` is static, not the class. C++ has no concept of a static class, only namespaces. Look in C# and like languages for static classes.

Answer (score 1):

The class is not static, it is the `class_tcphdr` that is static.